# Pivotting via Python and Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Has a table like this:

```
ID Word
1   take
2   the
3   long
4   long
5   road 
6   and
7   walk 
8   it
9   walk
10  it
```

Wanna to use pivot table in pandas to get distinct words in columns and 1 and 0 in Values. Smth like this matrix:

```
ID  Take The Long Road And Walk It
1    1    0   0    0    0   0    0
2    0    1   0    0    0   0    0
3    0    0   1    0    0   0    0
4    0    0   1    0    0   0    0
5    0    0   0    1    0   0    0
```

and so on

Trying to use pivot table but not familiar with pandas syntax yet:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.txt', sep='|', encoding='latin1')
table = pd.pivot_table(data,index=["ID"],columns=pd.unique(data["Word"].values),fill_value=0)
```

How can I rewrite pivot table function to deal with it?

Comment: isn't this `pd.get_dummies(df['Word'])` what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)with [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
print pd.concat([df['ID'], df['Word'].str.get_dummies()], axis=1)
   ID  and  it  long  road  take  the  walk
0   1    0   0     0     0     1    0     0
1   2    0   0     0     0     0    1     0
2   3    0   0     1     0     0    0     0
3   4    0   0     1     0     0    0     0
4   5    0   0     0     1     0    0     0
5   6    1   0     0     0     0    0     0
6   7    0   0     0     0     0    0     1
7   8    0   1     0     0     0    0     0
8   9    0   0     0     0     0    0     1
9  10    0   1     0     0     0    0     0
```

Or as [Edchum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720234/pivotting-via-python-and-pandas#comment59115658_35720234) mentioned in comments - [`pd.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
print pd.concat([df['ID'], pd.get_dummies(df['Word'])], axis=1)
   ID  and  it  long  road  take  the  walk
0   1    0   0     0     0     1    0     0
1   2    0   0     0     0     0    1     0
2   3    0   0     1     0     0    0     0
3   4    0   0     1     0     0    0     0
4   5    0   0     0     1     0    0     0
5   6    1   0     0     0     0    0     0
6   7    0   0     0     0     0    0     1
7   8    0   1     0     0     0    0     0
8   9    0   0     0     0     0    0     1
9  10    0   1     0     0     0    0     0
```